# How to convert ObjectID to String for text box binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, objectid

I've come across a binding error, when binding the ObjectID from my model to a textbox text property.

I know from Googling the error details, that the error is due to the textbox expecting a string value while the ObjectID is a hex value.

So in the ObjectID property I edited the setter to convert the ID to a string type. (But I get a conversion error, stating I can't implicitly convert the ObjectID to a String):

```
        set
        {
            id = Convert.ToString(value);
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can convert the ID to type string, in order to satisfy the text property binding on the text box?

The window data error I get are as follows:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' and 'System.String'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Id; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='customersgrid'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='iDTbx'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='5565d8adba02d54a4a78be96' BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Id; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='customersgrid'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='iDTbx'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

An example of the xaml binding is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MongoDBApp.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:email_validator="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validator"
        Title="Orders Dashbord"
        Width="800"
        Height="500">



    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Customer">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height=".50*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <DataGrid Name="customersgrid"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Grid.RowSpan="3"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="ID" />

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>


                    //ID textbox
                    <TextBox x:Name="iDTbx"
                             Grid.Row="4"
                             Grid.Column="2"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Width="120"
                             Height="23"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             BorderBrush="AliceBlue"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id,
                                            ElementName=customersgrid}"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Order" />

            <TabItem Header="OrderStatus" />

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This is the ObjectID property in the model, minus my conversion code that wasn't working:

```
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id 
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {

            id = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste some XAML as well? You should write a custom converter, and an example of XAML would help to answer

Comment: Added the xaml definition for the textbox now, not familiar with custom converters in this situation.

Comment: Do you actually want to edit the ID? You are setting `IsReadOnly="True"` on the TextBox, so you probably better use a TextBlock, where the Text property binds one-way by default, and the Binding would implicitly call the source property's `ToString()` method. No need for any explicit conversion then.

Comment: @Clemens, yes that's a perfect solution. I should have been using a textblock instead. Feel free to provide the solution as an answer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text` property of a TextBox binds two-way by default, which means that a conversion to and from `string` is necessary.

Since you are setting `IsReadOnly="True"` on your TextBox you seemingly only need a one-way binding, so you could write

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=customersgrid, Mode=OneWay}" .../>
```

Even better, don't use a TextBox at all when you don't want to edit the value. Use a TextBlock instead, where the `Text` property binds one-way by default. You don't need any converter then, because the Binding will implicitly convert the value to `string` by calling its `ToString()` method:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=customersgrid}" .../>
```